# Problem when creating bootable USB drive for Windows 10 installation

Tags: boot, iso, woeusb

When trying to create a bootable USB drive for Windows 10 on Ubuntu using WoeUSB and the Windows 10 iso, I'm getting this error after it attempts to install it to my drive. Some of it installs to the drive, just not it all.

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@

Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdb...
/dev/sdb: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (dos): 55 aa
/dev/sdb: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
Ensure that /dev/sdb is really wiped...
Creating new partition table on /dev/sdb...
Creating target partition...
Making system realize that partition table has changed...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
mkfs.fat: warning - lowercase labels might not work properly with DOS or Windows
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Mounting source filesystem...
Mounting target filesystem...
Applying workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
Copying files from source media...
cp: error reading './boot/en-us/bootsect.exe.mui': Input/output error
The command "cp "${source_file}" "${dest_file}"" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted
Resetting workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
/usr/bin/woeusb: line 1608: local: only_for_gui: readonly variable
Unmounting and removing '/media/woeusb_source_1524346346_31802'...
Unmounting and removing '/media/woeusb_target_1524346346_31802'...
You may now safely detach the target device
```

Comment: 1. Did you check that the iso file was downloaded correctly? 2. Try with mkusb according to this link, [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/837380#837380).

Comment: I've tried all of those steps and my problem is fixed.  When booting into the setup for w10, it asks me to 'select proper boot device and retry' or something along those lines. I've tried it in every slot in my BIOS I can,  quite obviously rebooting, making sure I've got all necessary files for the setup, nothing seems to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You write that your problem is fixed, and then that nothing seems to work. Please explain with more details, what you have done, what worked and what does not work.

Comment: My previous problem is fixed, but  I ran into a new problem. The problem with the exit code 256 with woeusb but when actually trying to boot into the windows 10 setup from the usb, im having this issue:  When booting into the setup for w10, it asks me to 'select proper boot device and retry' or something along those lines. I've tried it in every slot in my BIOS I can, quite obviously rebooting, making sure I've got all necessary files for the setup, nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: You should try to find out if the USB boot drive is bad or if you have not yet been able to make the computer boot from USB: 1. Please try in your computer with another USB boot drive, for example with Ubuntu; 2. and try with the Windows install drive in another computer (that might be easier to boot from USB).